# c# quicksort algorithm doesnt proceed

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have just worked on implementation of quicksort in c# but then I have faced a such a problem. When I am using my function

```
static void QS(int[] arr, int left, int right){
        int pivot = left;
        int temp;
        int i = left + 1;
        int j = left + 1;

        do {    
        if (arr [i] < arr [pivot]) {
                temp = arr [j];
                arr [j] = arr [i];
                arr [i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
            else{}
        j++;
        }while(j<=right);

            temp = arr [pivot];
            arr [pivot] = arr [i - 1];
            arr [i - 1] = temp;
}
```

For an array

```
int[] arr = { 12, 9, 19, 8, 7, 13, 10, 71, 18, 34, 90, 15, 3 };
```

I get the results like this: 
`9, 12, 19, 8, 7, 13, 10, 71, 18, 34, 90, 15, 3`. 
Hours been spent on this I still can't quite understand **why index i does not proceed**. Maybe there are more problems than I think.

I omitted recursive calls to concentrate on fuction itself. I am using this pseudo-code:

```
Partiton(A,l,r)  
//[input corresponds to A[l…r]]  
p:=A[l]  
i:=l+1  
  for  
   j=l+1 to r  
    if A[j] < p  
    swap A[j] and A[i]  
    i:=i+1  
swap  A[l] and A[i‐1]
```

Comment: the variable count is not declared

Comment: @Shekhar nor is it used; why would one declare it?

Comment: it was declared outside the function to see where index i fails to proceed, but i will remove it make code more clear

Comment: For one thing, quicksort is a recursive algorithm, and your code example does not recurse.

Comment: i omited recursive part of code to concentrate on function itself that produces wrong results even after first using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

Youre missing the comparisons(while loops) within the do while loop that move the index pointers, and the recursive calls that make quicksort actually work. Remember when you swap your values, increment i and decrement j. Second, for the values i and j, dont add 1 to those indexes as they could give you out of bounds errors, I assume you will be calling quicksort like so: quicksort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);. Finally, please choose your pivot as the median value as it yields much faster sorting time and results, rather than choosing the first value in the array.

Heres how I would write this:

```
   quicksort(arr[], begin, end)
   {
       pivot = (begin + end) / 2
       left = begin;
       right = end;
   while (left <= right)
   {
      while (arr[left] < pivot)
      {
          left++;
      }
      while (arr[right] > pivot)
      {
          right--;
      }
      if (left <= right)
      {
          swap(arr, left, right);
          left++;
          right--;
      }
  }
   //do your recursive call logic here
 }
```